# Get the latest value of an Observable and emit it immeditely

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm trying to get the latest value of a given `Observable` and get it to emit
immediately once it's called. Given the code below as an example:

```
return Observable.just(myObservable.last())
    .flatMap(myObservable1 -> {
        return myObservable1;
    })
    .map(o -> o.x) // Here I want to end up with a T object instead of Observable<T> object
```

This does not work because by doing this the `flatMap` will emit `myObservable1` which in turn will have
to emit to reach the `map`.
I don't know if doing such a thing is even possible. Does anyone have any clue on how to achieve this goal? Thank you

Comment: What observable are you talking about? What do you mean by latest?

Comment: `myObservable` is a hot observable which emit for example: "1", "2", "3" at irregular intervals. What I want to do is being able to get `myObservable` latest value ("3" in our case) at the time I reach the `return` directive

Comment: Is myObservable hot or cold?

Comment: Seems like you you are still thinking in imperative(not reactional) way. Could you give a bigger perspective? Point is that normally, you create observables based on other observables. You can create lastObservable based on myObservable, which will be blocked until myObservable ends, and then emit last value. There's no way out of these stream "tubes" except endpoints like subscribe.

Comment: I once asked a similar question on the RxJava Google Group - maybe Ben's answers there are helpful to you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rxjava/mihola/rxjava/I4CxPoU5rpE/v44DIj3Q2RAJ

Comment: ```startsWith``` for the default value and ```replay(1)``` + ```connect``` don't do the trick?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`last()` method will not be of any help here as it waits for the Observable to terminate to give you the last item emitted.

Assuming that you do not have the control over the emitting observable you could simply create a `BehaviorSubject` and subscribe it to the observable that emits the data that you want to listen and then subscribe to the created subject. Since `Subject` is both `Observable` and `Subscriber` you will get what you want.

I think (do not have the time to check it now) you may have to manually unsubscribe from the original observable as the `BehaviorSubject` once all of his subscribers unsubscribe will not unsubscribe automatically.

Something like this:

```
BehaviorSubject subject = new BehaviorSubject();
hotObservable.subscribe(subject);
subject.subscribe(thing -> {
    // Here just after subscribing 
    // you will receive the last emitted item, if there was any.
    // You can also always supply the first item to the behavior subject
});
```

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html

Answer (score 3):

In RxJava, subscriber.onXXX is called asynchronous.It means that if your Observable emit items in new thread, you can never get the last item before return, except you block the thread and wait for the item.But if the Observable emit item synchronously and you dont' change it's thread by subscribeOn and observOn,
such as the code:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3).subscribe();
```

In this case, you can get the last item by doing like this:

```
Integer getLast(Observable<Integer> o){
    final int[] ret = new int[1];
    Observable.last().subscribe(i -> ret[0] = i);
    return ret[0];
}
```

It's a bad idea doing like this.RxJava prefer you to do asynchronous work by it.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to achieve here is to take an asynchronous task and transform it to a synchronous one.

There are several ways to achieve it, each one with it's pros and cons:

- Use [toBlocking()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators) - it means that this thread will be BLOCKED, until the stream is finish, in order to get only one item simply use [first()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) as it will complete once an item is delivered.
  let's say your entire stream is `Observable<T> getData();`
  then a method that will get the last value immediately will look like this:

`public T getLastItem(){
    return getData().toBlocking().first();
}`

please don't use [last()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html) as it will wait for the stream to complete and only then will emit the last item.

If your stream is a network request and it didn't get any item yet this will block your thread!, so only use it when you are sure that there is an item available immediately (or if you really want a block...)

- another option is to simply cache the last result, something like this:

  getData().subscribe(t-> cachedT = t;) //somewhere in the code and it will keep saving the last item delivered
  public T getLastItem(){
      return cachedT;
  }

if there wasn't any item sent by the time you request it you will get null or whatever initial value you have set.
the problem with this approch is that the subscribe phase might happen after the get and might make a race condition if used in 2 different threads.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code here; what class is getLastItem applied to and what are the details of the getData() function?

Comment: GetData is just to emphasize a stream you are using.
You can replace it with the observable you are using, let's say myObservable in the original example 

Observable<T> myObservable;

Then 

myObservable.toBlocking().first()

Will give you the first item once it arrives.