# Merge two observables when Obs B depends on Obs A

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have two repository classes, repository A a List of Competitions as an Observable>.

My Competition class has a countryId.

I also have a repository B, which returns either a List of countries as an Observable> or a single country by Id as a Observable

I want to retrieve my list of competitions, and somehow merge it with their respective countries by returning a CountryCompetition class consisting of:

```
class CountryCompetition {
    public Country country;
    public Competition competition;
}
```

This means combinining my `competitionService.getCompetitions()` with `countryService.getCountry(competition.id)`, but I am not sure how to achieve this; `merge` or `zip` take an observable, and I dont have the ID of each country "yet".

```
 mCompetitionService.getCompetitions(wrapSearch(constraint))
                .flatMap(new Func1<List<Competition>, Observable<Competition>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Competition> call(List<Competition> competitions) {
                        return Observable.from(competitions);
                    }
                })

                .map(new Func1<Competition, CountryCompetition>() {
                    @Override
                    public CountryCompetition call(Competition competition) {
                        CountryCompetition c = new CountryCompetition();
                        c.setCompetition(competition);
//Here i would like to set the Country as well, but mCountryService.getCountryById(competition.getCountryId()) returns another observable.
                        return c;
                    }
                })
                .toList()
                .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
                .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: concat ? could be an option to ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42041934/3289338

Comment: I have trouble understanding that post. I posted some code to try and make it clearer what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have two lists and you want to basically merge them. You may found my solution useful:

Model classes (for sake of simplicity constructors are not included):

```
class Country {
    String name;
    String id;
}

class Competition {
    String name;
    String countryId;
}

class CountryCompetition {
    public Country country;
    public Competition competition;
}
```

Dummy data which follows your source `Observable`'s definitions:

```
public Observable<List<Competition>> getCompetitions() {
    ArrayList<Competition> competitions = new ArrayList<>();
    competitions.add(new Competition("First", "id_0"));
    competitions.add(new Competition("Second", "id_1"));
    competitions.add(new Competition("Third", "id_1"));
    competitions.add(new Competition("Fourth", "id_2"));
    competitions.add(new Competition("Fifth", "id_3"));

    return Observable.just(competitions);
}

public Observable<List<Country>> getCountries() {
    ArrayList<Country> competitions = new ArrayList<>();
    competitions.add(new Country("Germany", "id_0"));
    competitions.add(new Country("Czech Republic", "id_1"));
    competitions.add(new Country("Slovakia", "id_2"));
    competitions.add(new Country("Poland", "id_3"));

    return Observable.just(competitions);
}
```

And finally merge logic. I hope you're familiar with lambdas:

```
public void fun() {
    Observable.zip( // (1)
            getCompetitions(),
            getCountries(),
            Pair::create)
            .flatMap(pair -> getCompetitionsWithCountries(pair.first, pair.second)) // (2)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .subscribe(countryCompetitions -> {
                for (CountryCompetition countryCompetition : countryCompetitions) {
                    System.out.print(countryCompetition.toString()); // (6)
                }
            });
}

public Observable<List<CountryCompetition>> getCompetitionsWithCountries(List<Competition> competitions, List<Country> countries) {
    return Observable.from(competitions) // (3)
            .map(competition -> {
                Country country = searchForCountry(countries, competition.countryId); // (4)
                return new CountryCompetition(country, competition);
            })
            .toList(); // (5)
}

public Country searchForCountry(List<Country> countries, String countryId) {
    for (Country country : countries) {
        if (country.id.equals(countryId)) {
            return country;
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Country not found");
}
```

Explanation of interesting parts. :

1. `zip()` operator takes two observables and produces `Pair` of it's results. In this case, pair of two lists.
2. `flatMap()` operator takes this pair and returns new observable of type `Observable<List<CountryCompetition>>`
3. `from()` operator takes list of `Competition`s and emits every single `Competition` item separately to Rx chain.
4. Now we have single competition and list of countries, so we search for `Country` object based on `countryId`. Now we have both `Competition` and `Country` objects and we can `map()` them to new `CountryCompetition` object.
5. Pack all emitted `CountryCompetition` items back to the list.
6. Print results. Type of the object `countryCompetitions` is `List<CountryCompetition>`

Answer (score 0):

Not super complex:

```
  public Observable<CountryCompetition> getCountyComps(){
      return getCompetitions()
                 .flatMap(competition ->
                      Observable.zip(
                      Observable.just(competition),
                      getCountry(competition.id)),
                      (comp, country) -> new CountryCompetition(comp, country))
    }
```